# How can I output an error message in my currency converter if the user inputs wrong value?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could output an error message telling the user to enter a whole number or a decimal number if they input a special symbol such as "#" or a character letter into the amount of my currency converter program.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/liamdocherty1/pen/LygEEq)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Fetch exchange rate data from api
$.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=ZAR", function(data) {
  var currencies = [];
  $.each(data.rates, function(currency, rate) {
    // Currency options dropdown menu
    currencies.push("<option id='" + currency.toLowerCase() + "' value='" + rate + "' >" + currency + "</option>");
  });
  $(".currency-list").append(currencies);
})

//Calculate and output the new amount
function exchangeCurrency() {
  var amount = $(".amount").val();
  var rateFrom = $(".currency-list")[0].value;
  var rateTo = $(".currency-list")[1].value;
  if (amount == undefined || rateFrom == "--Select--" || rateTo == "--Select--") {
    $(".results").html("0");
  } else {
    $(".results").html((amount * (rateTo * (1 / rateFrom))).toFixed(2));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the number is valid (before other checks) using one of many JS methods (regex, isNaN etc) and then show or hide some error element accordingly. Number verify methods vary when it comes to some edge/specific cases, but using "number" field alone will prevent most of the bad inputs:
[pen](https://codepen.io/mackie_pl/pen/BRqKGq)

```
//Calculate and output the new amount
function exchangeCurrency() {
  var amount = $(".amount").val();
  var rateFrom = $(".currency-list")[0].value;
  var rateTo = $(".currency-list")[1].value;
  if ((amount - 0) != amount || (''+amount).trim().length == 0) {
    $(".results").html("0");
    $(".error").show()
  } else {
    $(".error").hide()
    if (amount == undefined || rateFrom == "--Select--" || rateTo == "--Select--") {
      $(".results").html("0");

    } else {
      $(".results").html((amount * (rateTo * (1 / rateFrom))).toFixed(2));
    }
  }
}
```